# custom post type breadcrumb error when has_archive = false

Tags: custom-post-types, breadcrumb

I have a custom post type (team) and I do not use archive page (has_archive => false), when I visit single team post the breadcrumb contains inactive text "TeamSingleTitle". I would like to know how I can modify the breadcrumb function to remove this "Team" custom post name from the breadcrumb.  I can't hide it using CSS as it's appended directly in front of the SingleTitle without even a space.  If I change has_archive to true then it all works correctly and Team is created as a link and spaced accordingly.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the relevant code, so that we can try to help with debugging etc.

Comment: It's not a code issue it's an issue due to the archive being set to false, the breadcrumb is still picking up the custom post type name and adding it to the breadcrumb. I'd just like to know the function to stop the breadcrumb from grabbing the custom post type name

Comment: What are you using to generate your breadcrumbs? Is it a plugin or is it custom code written by you or someone else? If the former, then try the plugin's support forum; if the latter, then please, show us the code. **Edited to add** It might also be helpful to see the code that sets up the `team` custom post type.

Comment: I'm not using any plugin - it's just the breadcrumb generated by Genesis theme/Wordpress

Comment: A stock install of WordPress doesn't have breadcrumbs. That'll be a Genesis feature. If you've bought the framework, they offer support -- http://my.studiopress.com/themes/genesis . Also, Googling [`genesis theme breadcrumb`](https://www.google.ca/search?q=genesis+theme+breadcrumb) turned up a bunch of hits -- maybe one of them is what you need. [Support for third-party themes (like Genesis) is beyond the scope of WordPress Stack Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I'm afraid.

Comment: That's OK i just worked it out so have posted my answer below in case any one else is looking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just grabbed a snippet from the get_cpt_crumb() function in the genesis breadcrumbs class file (/lib/classes/breadcrumb.php)

```
protected function get_cpt_crumb() {
    $post_type = get_query_var( 'post_type' );
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post_type );

    if ( $cpt_archive_link = get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type ) )
        $crumb = $this->get_breadcrumb_link( $cpt_archive_link, sprintf( __( 'View all %s', 'genesis' ), $post_type_object->labels->name ), $post_type_object->labels->name );
    else
        $crumb = $post_type_object->labels->name;

    $crumb .= $this->args['sep'] . single_post_title( '', false );

    return $crumb;
}
```

I just set my crumb to grab only the title and not the archives.

```
function eco_crumb_filter( $crumb, $args ) {
if ( is_singular( 'team' )  )
    return single_post_title( '', false );
else
    return $crumb;
}
add_filter( 'genesis_single_crumb', 'eco_crumb_filter', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: is it an answer, is it part of the question? what is this code?

Comment: I found the solution to my own question

Comment: then please accept it, the system thinks it still needs an answer and bumps it :(